# SlidingPaneLayout messy on low resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-layout-weight, slidingpanelayout

I have a SlidingPaneLayout in my application and I want it to appear more or less like Hangouts does. I show a list of elements on the left and the detail on the right pane, overlapping when an element is selected.

This is what I see on my Galaxy Nexus, which is pretty what I meant to see:

[image]

[image]

Now, this is what I get on my old Galaxy S:

[image]
[image]

The code is pretty simple:

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/list_pane"
            android:name="com.towers.hotelsclickpoc.ResultsCardsFragment"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:layout_gravity="left"></fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/content_pane"
            android:name="com.towers.hotelsclickpoc.DetailsFragment"
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"></fragment>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

How can I make the layout look pretty the same on the two devices? As you can see I tried adding some weights but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems like I managed to get it fixed.

The inner part of SlidingPaneLayout now looks like this:

```
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_pane"
        android:name="com.towers.hotelsclickpoc.ResultsCardsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"></fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/content_pane"
        android:name="com.towers.hotelsclickpoc.DetailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"></fragment>
```

it seems the layout_width="match_parent" on BOTH fragments did the trick.

I hope this will be helpful to others.